# Galaxy Tab on device debug?

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging

Any body gotten on device debugging working wit hthe Galaxy Tab? I have a Stock Generic Galaxy Tab and Although Eclpise will let me "Run" my apps on the device, if I click "Debug" in eclpise instead it doesn't do anything nor does it try to connect to the debugger.

Ideas?

**UPDATE: Solution was to explicitly set my application to debuggable in the manifest. If the device (Galaxy Tab) is not set to default in it's boot image, it will not implicitly allow debugging.**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same problem. As well as setting the Galaxy Tab into debug mode (as described by Computerish), you also need to download Samsung Kies from [the Samsung website](http://www.samsung.com) (browse to the Galaxy Tab page, then to Support). This gives you the required drivers to use the Tab in debug mode: without them, the Tab won't appear in the Eclipse Run or Debug dialogs.

Comment: UPDATE: With Samsung Tab S 10.5, the solution was to download & install "USB Driver for Samsung Android Mobile Devices" on my Windows PC.  Samsung / Support / your-device-and-model / Downloads / USB Driver.  For me, http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/SM-T800NTSAXAR  When this USB Driver is connected to the phone, the phone shows dialog requesting permission to turn on USB Debugging. (First, on the tablet, I enabled the hidden Developer Options and turned on USB Debugging.)

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that USB debugging is enabled. Go to Settings > Applications > Development and then make sure that the USB debugging checkbox is checked. A USB debugging notification should appear when you connect your Tab to the computer.

Comment: I have debugging on, like I said, I can "Run" the app to the device but it won't connect to the debugger if I click debug. I normally develop on a HTC Desire so I wouldn't miss so simple. I noticed the tab _never_ shows "Debugging" notification as the Desire normally does, I wasn't sure if Samsung just hid it since i'v never seen it on the Tab.

Comment: There is a second setting for showing the debugging notification so that might be why the notification doesn't show up. That still isn't going to solve your problem, though. Does eclipse switch to the debugging perspective? Can you see LogCat output during normal running?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have Developer options on your device, read this post. It saved my bacon.

http://gs4.wonderhowto.com/how-to/enable-hidden-developer-options-your-samsung-galaxy-s4-0146687/

Answer (score 1):

Download [**SAMSUNG KIES**](http://www.samsung.com/ca/support/mobilesoftwaremanual/mobilesoftwaremanual.do?page=MOBILE.SOFTWARE.MANUAL) (it contains the Drivers that you need) and you will be able to debug your Samsung Android Tablet.

Comment: Not relevant in this case, the drivers had already been installed. But yes, Kies will indeed install the drivers for those without, and if it does not, Kies provides an option in the Tools menu "Install Driver".

Comment: ok Hamid in my case i just installed the drivers and don´t need enable the android:debuggable property to debug.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an updated link that works for me.

The KIES download link does not appear to be active.

http://innovator.samsungmobile.com/cms/cnts/knowledge.detail.view.do?platformId=1&cntsId=9480

Comment: sorry, duplicate of  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6238191/debugging-apps-on-a-galaxy-tab-10-1