# Debugging apps on a Galaxy Tab 10.1

Tags: android, eclipse, adb

I'm trying to work with a Galaxy Tab 10.1 on Windows 7 but I'm having some troubles. At the time to debug my apps on the tab, the eclipse not recognizing the debugging device and opens the emulator.

Someone have any ideas about that?

**EDIT:**
I resolved the problem following this link: dkszone.net/setup-install-adb-android-debug-bridge-windows-7 Thanks to all.

Comment: Do you have proper drivers for Samsung devices?

Comment: Did you install the drivers for the tab?

Comment: How can you usb deubg the galaxy tab 10.1 if it doesn't have a usb port? (http://www.samsung.com/global/microsite/galaxytab/10.1/spec.html)

Comment: Because it comes with a cable that converts from its port to usb on a computer...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you checked http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html#setting-up
also the Samsung USB Driver should be available here http://innovator.samsungmobile.com/down/cnts/toolSDK.detail.view.do?platformId=1&cntsId=9480
it's all part of [Samsungs Mobile Developer Page](http://innovator.samsungmobile.com/platform.main.do?platformId=1)

Answer (score 1):

I had similar trouble when pluging my Galaxy tab 101 in a port on my keyboard.

As soon as i plugged into a regular USB port on my computer, all went fine.

Answer (score 1):

The solutions above did not work for me.  The links appear to be out of date.  The main article on how to set up for development is at http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html#setting-up (as mentioned above).  This connects to an OEM USB Drivers page at http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html.  The directions there did not work for me: There is no "Other" item in my Device manager, and I did not find a driver on the Samsung site http://www.samsung.com/us/support/downloads# for my device (GT-80013), only manuals.

What did work was to install KIES as described at http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1903483.  That's all I had to do, and it magically appeared.  For the record there is now a "Samsung Android Phone" item in my Device manager.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a thread that helped me to solve similar problem.
http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/3571170253b99d0/92c8a626e08e2574

Answer (score 0):

+1 Richard Lalancette 's comment, make sure the tab is plugged into a USB2.0 port.

Other things that may be issue: 
1. Double check that you have enabled "Developer Options" on your tablet and the option for "USB Debugging" is checked. 
2. When you connect your tab to your windows pc, you should get a message asking you to accept your computers RSA fingerprint. Click "Ok" to accept.

If all the above has been done and the tab is still not being recognised then you can update drivers for the device, download kies etc etc