# Android Processing programming will not run application on device. How do I fix this?

Tags: java, android, processing

I'm currently working with Processing, and I would like to code an android app. I have succeeded in being able to launch may application in the android emulator, but I am not able to get it to launch on my Galaxy 2.0 tab. I click run device, but every time I do I get a message at the end that says "waiting for device to become available". I'm thinking that I may need to point Processing to my android tablet somehow. Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong. I'm on Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

It means your device is not being detected in the eclipse debugger tool. Did you check in Tab "Developer Options", make sure USB debugging is enabled. please refer other links you may get answer.
[Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4179178/galaxy-tab-on-device-debug)

[Device not detected in Eclipse when connected with USB cable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8063147/device-not-detected-in-eclipse-when-connected-with-usb-cable)